# How can I calculate the minimum value of $2^m-k \cdot 3^n$?

Tags: number-theory

I understand that the minimum value of $2^m-k \cdot 3^n$ is "effectively computable".

Is it *actually* computable, and if so, how do I compute it?

If it helps, I'm primarily interested in the case when $2^m > k \cdot 3^n > 2^{m-1}$, i.e the difference between $k \cdot 3^n$ and the next higher power of $2$.

Comment: Presumably you want the minimum *positive* value, and presumably you want the minimum for each fixed $k$, since you clearly can't do better than $2^2-1\cdot3^1=1$. (Oh, wait, if you want $2^m\lt k*3^n\lt2^{m+1}$, then you're getting negative values.  Are you really asking about the absolute value?)

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean the min. value of $$ 2^{m+1} -k*3^n$$

Comment: Yes, sorry, I corrected the last bit so it makes more sense.

Comment: You need more restrictions to make the problem nontrivial. Leaving $k$ and $n$ free I get all solutions in $d_m = \min(|2^m-k\cdot 3^n|)=1$ for all $m$ because either $2^m-1$ or $2^m+1$ is divisible by $3$ and thus gives a solution with integer $k$ and power of $3$.

Comment: What if k is fixed and m and n are variable?

Comment: Joe: then it is different ... ;-) Please make then your question more precise so we can really answer (if still needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=2^m$ then either $a+1$ or $a-1$ is divisible by $3$ such that $a+1=3k$ or $a-1=3k$. If , as you ask, $2^m \gt a=k3^n \gt ...$ then instead of $a+1=3k$ we would write $a-2 = 3k$ and we have $2^m - k3 = r ; r\in \{1,2\}$ and more precisely $2^{2m_1} -3k = 1$ and $2^{2m_1+1} -3k = 2$ .

---

There are more informative general expressions for the ***neighboured*** case ($2^m-k3^n=1$) even in terms of powers of $3$:
 $$2^m -1 =k3^n \qquad \implies n= [m:2] (1+ \{m,3\})$$ 
where $[a:b]$ is the "Iverson-bracket" evaluating to $ [a:b] = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{ if } b \mid a \\ 0 &\text{ if } b \not \mid a \end{cases}  $
and $\{a,p\}=e$ gives the exponent of the primefactor $p$ in the primefactorization in $a$.

For the ***non-neighboured*** case $2^m - k3^n =2 $ we have thus the similar expression
 $$2^m -2=2(2^{m-1}-1) =k3^n \qquad \implies n= [m-1:2] (1+ \{m-1,3\})$$